# R New Line Print from Data Frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame that has 10 entries each numbered. When I print the data frame it outputs everything like this

```
1.entry 2.entry 3. entry 4. entry and so on..
```

I want it to look like this

```
1.Entry
2.Entry
3.Entry
4.Entry
```

This is my current code

```
print(Tracks_df$Tracks)
```

This is a Shiny app and this code is being used in the Server Side

Comment: Try this: `print(Tracks_df['Tracks'])`

Comment: Or try `print(Tracks_df[ , 'Tracks', drop=FALSE])`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
cat(as.vector(Tracks_df$Tracks),sep='\n')
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing comes up now